# how to make field only editable by system (not admin or users)

Tags: django, forms, models

I need some fields in my model for internal usages (i.e. status, last modified, etc.) which should only editable (and fillable) by python code.

How to hide it in Django Admin and disable direct editing from forms?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup Custom Django Admin to do the same.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     exclude = ('field_1', 'field_2')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it is still editable in user forms. isn't it?. (if user manipulate Request data and add a value for my hidden field).. Should I exclude it again in my form definition?

Comment: I am not sure. It's not hidden but complete excluded from the form itself. I think django should be including those fields in the server side form validation and save.